# Mobile Navigation Menu not working (HTML, CSS & JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am attempting to make a mobile navigation menu based off of this example: [Basic Hamburger Menu](http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/KbFcg)

However, for what ever reason it does not work.  When I click on the button nothing happens except rotating the 3-line graphic.  The menu does not expand / appear.

When troubleshooting I have found out that if .mobile is site for display:block; instead of display:none; when the page loads, the javascript works for collapsing / hiding the menu, and making it reappear.  Only the rotation of the 3-line graphic is opposite of what it should be.  So, I know the javascript is working.

I just can't understand why it doesn't work with the nav hidden by default like in the example.  I have played around with it for more then 3 hours so far and have gotten nowhere.  There for I"m attempting to post it here to see if anyone might have any idea as to what might be going on as I am at a complete loss and about ready to wave the white flag.

This is the javascript on my page:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded').siblings('div').slideToggle();
});
//@ sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
```

And the HTML / CSS is the same as the example except I have modified it so all the links are built into a UL.

HTML Code:

```html
<div id="main_container">
    <header>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/header3.jpg" alt"logo" width="100%">
    </header>
     <nav>
        <div id="desktop_nav"><?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?></div>
     </nav>
     <nav>
        <div id="mobile_nav" class="mobile">
         <button>Toggle</button>
   <div>
          <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?> 
         </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
```

And CSS Code:

```css
#mobile_nav ul {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 /*table-layout:fixed;*/
}

.mobile {
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 min-height:50px;
}

.mobile div {
 display:none;
}

.mobile button {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left: 10px;
 border:0;
 text-indent:200%;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#363636 url(assets/menu.png) center no-repeat;
 border-radius:3px;
 background-size:80%;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 outline:none;
 transition:all 400ms ease;
 -webkit-transition:all 400ms ease;
 transition:all 400ms ease;
}

.mobile button.expanded {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
 transform:rotate(90deg);
 border:0;
}

.mobile ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;

}

.mobile ul li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
 display: table-cell;
}

.mobile ul li a:hover,
.mobile ul li a:active,
.mobile ul li a:focus {
  background: #363636;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
 .mobile {
  display:block;
 }
 .mobile div {display:block}

 #desktop_nav {
  display:none;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your HTML with the UL?

Comment: Added HTML & CSS Code.  UL comes from Wordpress.

.moble div {display:block} in the media query makes the javascript work in reverse.  Without that line of code nothing happens at all other than rotating the 3 line icon on the button.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the click function is looking for siblings of a div, but the link elements are now within a ```ul``` and ```li``` and so the ```siblings``` code portion must be updated to reflect that. Also, because you are using php, you might want to wrap your jQuery in ```$(document).ready```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll play around with the siblings code portion tomorrow to see if that makes a difference.  Will also try to wrap the jQuery as well.

Comment: Still at a complete loss on this one.  I have tried changing the code from siblings to find and placed a class on the div.  When I do this I run into the same result, the code does nothing when the the page loads and the toggle state is set to display none.  But when the page loads and the toggle state is display block it will hide and bring back the div.   I just don't get it.

Comment: Googling I have found that this is an issue that sometimes happens with slideToggle and the initial display set to none.  There was a work around posted, but like like like on that support page thew workaround causes the loss of the animation.  The solution that solved that issue was a pure CSS Animation, so I'm going to go and give that a try and see if that makes a difference for me.

Comment: The CSS solution did not work for me, this is because the hight of the div being toggled changes with the amount of li elements in the navigation.

However, I did solve my javascript issue finally.  The following code works, don't ask me why making  it multiple lines works. 

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  
  jQuery('button').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  jQuery(".toggle").slideToggle();
 });
});
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class to the div called "toggle" and changing the format of the javascript to the following solved the issue.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  
  jQuery('button').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  jQuery(".toggle").slideToggle();
 });
});
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```